# How to get the server JSON response in Sencha Touch?

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

I've created an AJAX request in a function. However, I am not sure how to return the JSON result - can anyone show me how?

```
function getData(arg1, arg2, arg3){

    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: 'getData.php',
        params: {
            arg1: arg1,
            arg2: arg2,
            arg3: arg3
        },
        method: 'POST',
        success: function(response, opts) {
            var jsonData = Ext.util.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
            console.log(jsonData);   <-- Can see the result here!
        },
        failure: function(response, opts) {
            console.log('server-side failure with status code ' + response.status);
        }
    });
    return /jsonData/    <-- Here is the value I want?!

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your `jsonData` won't get any information if you use it in your `getData` functions is - when the success callback returns (remember, the request is asynchronous) - the `getData` scope is already exited.

What you can and should do is define a handler function:

```
function handleSuccess( response, opts )
{
   var jsonData = Ext.util.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
   // use jsonData here in whatever way you please
}
```

then define your `getData` like so:

```
function getData(arg1, arg2, arg3){

    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: 'getData.php',
        params: {
            arg1: arg1,
            arg2: arg2,
            arg3: arg3
        },
        method: 'POST',
        success: handleSuccess,
        failure: handleError
    });
    // Note the lack of return statement.
}
```

Of course, you can do the same with your error handling:

```
function handleError( response, opts )
{
   console.log('server-side failure with status code ' + response.status);
}
```

**Update**

there is no way for you to do something like that (where `result` will get the server response):

```
...
var result = getData('arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3');
...
```

reliably and still call an **AJAX** request. If you think about it - had the above been possible it would essentially become a *synchronous* request.

The two ways to do your calculations upon `jsonData` that contains server response are:

1) Do it in `handleSuccess` function and adjust the rest of your code accordingly (as a side not - you can pass the handler functions as parameters to `Ext.Ajax` in `options.callback` and )

2) Make your server request synchronous (not advisable) by usual means

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. And yes I understand what you mean, but my aim is to get the value that returned from the server, and this value 'jsonData' will be use in another function for calculation. How can I do that?

Comment: Thanks ZenMaster, i really appreciate your explanations. Is there any chance to accomplish this kind of task by using the store?

Comment: @user888022 no, not really, since the loading of the store would be asynchronous as well - the difference would be that you would have to either use one of the components that use store by default or, if you want to manipulate the data by yourself, you would have to bind some handler to store's `datachanged` event (or similar) - which is basically the same thing as what you do above. The difference when using store is that, if your data is "tabular", you get to enjoy store's built-in API - sort, filter etc.